# Inputting a random date into a cell - Excel VBA

Tags: vba, date, excel, random

Doing some research on this and i found there are ways to generate random dates in a range using functions within the excel spreadsheet like so:

```
 =DATE(2010, 1, 1)+LARGE(IF(WEEKDAY(DATE(2010, 1, 1)+ROW($1:$365)-1, 2)<6, ROW($1:$365)-1, ""), RANDBETWEEN(1, SUM(--(WEEKDAY(DATE(2010, 1, 1)+ROW($1:$365)-1, 2)<6))))
```

is there a way I can do this and insert it straight into a cell like

```
Cells(i, "F").Value = //Random Date//
```

Comment: Do you mean any random date - e.g. 23rd Feb 1423 and 16th Dec 2345 are acceptable - or do you want a specified date range?

Comment: like between a range say 1/1/1990 - 1/1/2012, and in a format like that too ?

Comment: RANDBetween doesn't seem to be built in into excel-vba, would i need to define it somewhere else ?

Comment: @pnuts - being pedantic...`1` should be `32874` for OPs stated date range. But it's the simplest way to solve this one (+1)

Comment: @pnuts - haha! Yes, I thought you must have misread it as 1/1/1900...happy trails...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The VBA way:

```
Sub RandomDates()
    Dim startDate As Date, endDate As Date, randomDate As Date

    startDate = "1/1/1990"
    endDate = "1/1/2012"

    Cells(i, "f") = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(startDate, endDate)
    Cells(i, "f").NumberFormat = "d/m/yyyy"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the **pnuts** approach:

```
Sub dural()
    i = 1
    d1 = DateValue("1/1/1990")
    d2 = DateValue("1/1/2012")
    Cells(i, "F").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(d1, d2)
    Cells(i, "F").NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

to translate your function into VBA:

```
=DateSerial(2001,1,1) + Int(Rnd*365)
```

If you need to check the weekday, then vba has a WeekDay function too.

Answer (score 0):

you can use RANDBETWEEN() to generate random dates for a specific time period. You'll include the DATE() function to specify the bottom and top values as dates, using the form

```
RANDBETWEEN(DATE(bottomdate),DATE(topdate))
```

OR

```
RANDBETWEEN(DATE(bottomdate);DATE(topdate))
```

test use`,` or `;` in `RANDBETWEEN()` function.

For example, to return random dates between January 1, 2014 and January 30, 2014, you'd use the following function:

```
=RANDBETWEEN(DATE(2014,1,1),DATE(2014,1,30))
```

Reference: [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/generate-random-dates-within-a-specific-date-range/)